# How to get altitude from qt map.tocoordinate(Qt.point())?

Tags: qt, qml

I have been trying to get the Map coordinates from QML map (Qt5.12) with the MouseArea. But the problem is that I only get the value of latitude and longitude and the altitude is zero. I have walk the document, and still don't know how to explain it better. Here is a part of my code:

```
    onPositionChanged: {
        flightMap.focus = true
        var coordinate = flightMap.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y), false)

        coordinate.latitude = coordinate.latitude.toFixed(_decimalPlaces)
        coordinate.longitude = coordinate.longitude.toFixed(_decimalPlaces)
        coordinate.altitude = coordinate.altitude.toFixed(_decimalPlaces)
        coordlabel.text ="coordPosition: " + coordinate.latitude.toFixed(6)
                                    + ", " + coordinate.longitude.toFixed(6)
                                    + ", " + coordinate.altitude.toFixed(6)

        mouselabel.text ="mousePosition: " + mouse.x.toFixed(2) +
                                      ", " + mouse.y.toFixed(2) +
                            " zoomLevel: " + Math.floor(flightMap.zoomLevel);
    }
```

altitude is 0

[image]

map provider： Bing

```
[
{
    "name":             "mapProvider",
    "shortDescription": "Currently selected map provider for flight maps",
    "type":             "string",
    "defaultValue":     "Bing"
},
{
    "name":             "mapType",
    "shortDescription": "Currently selected map type for flight maps",
    "type":             "string",
    "defaultValue":     "Hybrid"
}
]
```

Comment: what map provider do you use? please provide [mcve]

Comment: @folibis Bing map

Comment: Thanks, can you provide [mcve] now?